# Why is it that i am getting a 404 on Github when trying to publish a site on Git Hubs platform

Tags: github, http-status-code-404

Below is the website that i created thru GitHub.

I followed a tutorial to get here , the tutorial advised me to wait 30 mins for the server to clear up.

and it didn't what should i do now?

Below is the link to the site

https://wildcardpossibiliites.github.io/cv/

Sincerely

Answer (score 0):

Just checked your repo at https://github.com/WildCardPossibiliites/cv

The problem is your repo doesn't include a `index.html` file but `Index.html`.
If you replace it to `index.html`, it will be fixed. Otherwise, you can see the intended page at https://wildcardpossibiliites.github.io/cv/Index.html